# Dart Verificar se uma data é válida

Tags: dart

Como verificar se uma data é válida em Dart?

Mesmo informando uma data inválida não retornar nenhum tipo de exceção

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
void main() {
    print ('dart');
    print(DateFormat.yMd().parse('31/31/2019')); 
    // resultado 2021-07-31 00:00:00.000
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz alguns testes diretamente no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) e o `parse` já faz essa verificação de data

```
print(DateTime.parse("2019-12-26"));
/* Resultado: (Data) 2019-12-26 00:00:00.000 */

print(DateTime.parse("31/31/2019"));
/* Resultado: Uncaught Error: FormatException: Invalid date format 31/31/2019*/
```

Na documentação podemos ver as seguintes Strings aceitas:

```
• "2012-02-27 13:27:00"<br>   
• "2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456z"<br>   
• "2012-02-27 13:27:00,123456z"<br>   
• "20120227 13:27:00"<br>   
• "20120227T132700"<br>   
• "20120227"<br>    
• "+20120227"<br>   
• "2012-02-27T14Z"<br>   
• "2012-02-27T14+00:00"<br>   
• "-123450101 00:00:00 Z": in the year -12345.<br>   
• "2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500": Same as "2002-02-27T19:00:00Z"
```

**Explicação para o seu caso**

Uma coisa que percebi é que quando informamos um mês que não existe, por exemplo o mês 14, o `parse` por conta de seus cálculos internos "reinicia a contagem".

Posso dizer o seguinte, se o mês for maior que 12, basta você subtrair 12 desse mês que chegará ao mês que o `parse` irá retornar, por exemplo:

A data que você utilizou "31/31/2019" retornou "2021-07-31 00:00:00.000".

> *Porque disso?*
>
> ```
> 31-12=19
> 19-12=7
> ```
>
> Ou seja, ele jogou a data pro mês 7 do próximo ano.

Isso que expliquei acima é um problema antigo que ainda não foi corrigido ainda... Mesmo sendo algo de uma grande importância.

Deixo aqui alguns links sobre o problema

[DateTime.parse should throw an error on invalid date](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/11189)

[How to check if a given Date exists in DART?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57080005/10145630)

**Como contornar?**

De acordo com o último link acima, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
void main() {
  var inputs = ['20180101', // -> 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000
                '20181231', // -> 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000
                '20180230', // -> 2018-03-02 00:00:00.000
                '20181301', // -> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
                '20181364'];// -> 2019-03-05 00:00:00.000

  inputs.forEach((input) {
    print("$input is valid string: ${isValidDate(input)}");
  });
}

bool isValidDate(String input) {
  final date = DateTime.parse(input);
  final originalFormatString = toOriginalFormatString(date);
  return input == originalFormatString;
}

String toOriginalFormatString(DateTime dateTime) {
  final y = dateTime.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0');
  final m = dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  final d = dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  return "$y$m$d";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Um simples função

```
bool isValidDate(String date) {
  try {
    DateTime.parse(date);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Você aplica assim:**

```
if (!isValidDate(store.nasc)) {
    store.message = 'Data informa é inválida!';
    store.setError();
    return;
}
```