# Como verificar se uma data é dia útil?

Tags: dart

Como verificar se uma data é dia útil ? Abaixo está meu código de exemplo:

```
void main() {

   var now = new DateTime.now();
   var berlinWallFell = new DateTime.utc(1989, 11, 9);
   var moonLanding = DateTime.parse("1969-07-20 20:18:04Z");  // 8:18pm

   print(now);

   // Colocar aqui uma verificação se é dia útil.

}
```

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? É só comparar se o dia não é sexta, sábado ou feriado, dependendo da lógica é claro.

Comment: Você diz dias que não sejam sábado e domingo? Ou feriados no geral?

Comment: De uma olhada aqui nessa pergunta [Dart Verificar se uma data é válida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427311/87785), mesmo se não atender ao seu caso, você entenderá um pouco mais sobre!

Answer (score 3):

No geral, dias úteis são aqueles que não são sábado, domingo ou feriado.

Tomando isso por base um modo de se fazer seria:

```dart
void main() {
  // Data que está validando se é dia util.
  var data = DateTime(2020,02,25);  

  var diaUtil = !ehSabadoOuDomingo(data) && !ehFeriado(data);

  print(diaUtil);
}

bool ehSabadoOuDomingo(DateTime data){
  var diaDaSemana = data.weekday;

  // O "weekday" de uma instancia de data retorna um
  // inteiro referente ao dia da semana. Sábado e domingo
  // são representados respectivamente por 6 e 7.
  return diaDaSemana == 6 || diaDaSemana == 7;
}

bool ehFeriado(DateTime data){

  // Informar a lista de dias no ano que são considerados
  // feriados nacionais. Vai ser necessário pesquisar quais são
  // e ir inserindo aqui nesta lista. Coloquei apenas alguns exemplos.
  var diasDeFeriado = [
    DateTime(2020,01,01),
    DateTime(2020,02,25),
    DateTime(2020,04,21),
  ];

  return diasDeFeriado.contains(data);
}
```

Este é apenas um exemplo. Pode ser copiado e colado no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dart) para testar.

Comment: Seria interessante ao se referir ao [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) você colocar um link para redirecionar a ele, muita gente não sabe do que se trata.

Comment: Boa dica, editei a resposta adicionando o link.